# Pyttsx3 not supporting python executable

Tags: python, terminal, executable, text-to-speech, pyttsx3

I coded a simple program in python (Pyttsx3 module) that narrates any text entered by the user. So I converted this into an executable file so that I can use it on my desktop. when I tried running it the terminal open and closed nothing happened. for a split second I was able to see there was a problem with the pyttsx3 module ( module not found). how can I fix this, pls help.

Comment: A sample of the Python script along with details on how you made the executable file would be helpful!

Comment: Please provide the source code and any logs or error traces.